# When and why kernel_size may be 1 or 2 dims when using Conv2D?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

When using `Conv2D` we can define the `kernel_size` to be 1 dim or 2 dims (or higher value of dims)

for example:

```
Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu')
```

or

```
Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu')
```

1. When using `Conv2D` , what is the recommendations ?
2. What are the cases we will choose to use `1D` (`kernel_size=7`) and what are the cases we will prefer to choose `2D` (`kernel_size=(3,3)`) or other dim ?
3. Does the choosing the dim of `kernel_size` will affect the choosing of pooling size ? (`MaxPooling2D(pool_size=?)`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. (and 2) ):

> kernel_size: An integer or tuple/list of 2 integers, specifying the
> height and width of the 2D convolution window. Can be a single integer
> to specify the same value for all spatial dimensions.

[Keras doc](https://keras.io/api/layers/convolution_layers/convolution2d/). Conv2D performs convolution with 2D filter, it can be square (use single int to define) or not square (use tuple). Regarding size of filter (3, 7, etc.) choice depends on task and architecture. See [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63427011/14161847) for basic intuition behind particular example

3. Kernel_size as well as stride and padding affect Conv2D output shape, and you should take that into account if you want `MaxPooling2D` output of specific shape.

Answer (score 1):

The kernel size for Conv2D is always 2 dimensional

[here](https://keras.io/api/layers/convolution_layers/convolution2d/)

> kernel_size: An integer or tuple/list of 2 integers, specifying the
> height and width of the 2D convolution window. Can be a single integer
> to specify the same value for all spatial dimensions.

You just have the option to write kernel size 3 but in reality means (3,3).
For Conv1D, the kernel size is 1d also.

If you use Conv2D you must choose MaxPooling2D , if you use Conv1D you must choose MaxPooling1D.